# How do I get this to add 2+2=4 instead of the answer being 2?

Tags: python

```
number1 = input("2")
number1 = int(number1) 

number2 = input("2")
number2 = int(number2) 
sum = number1 + number2

print("Sum of numbers is", sum)
```

## In this code I want to do number1 + number2 to add together to become 4, but it gives me 2.

Comment: What did you input for those prompts? Also are you on python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using python 3 in trinket

Comment: The string passed into the input function is for the prompt to the user, not the value. Try replace with `input("Enter your number:")` and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is working fine here: sum equals 4.

But you need to know what you are doing:

```
numberx = input("something")
```

This shows `something` on screen, and whatever you type after this, becomes the value of `numberx`.

So, if you do `number1 = input("2")`, then you see:

```
2
```

(at that moment you are expected to type something)

Most probably you have typed "2" (you see 22 on your screen), and this means that `number1` is now 2.

This is all very confusing, therefore you might replace `input("2")` by `input("Enter your number:")`, as proposed by RobertLayton. It will be far more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
number1 = input("2")
```

Here you are writing 2 to the output and storing the value that the user or you give. So the program is waiting for an input that you have to give in the console.

```
print("Give two numbers:")
number1 = input()
number2 = input()
sum = int(number1)+int(number2)
print("Sum of numbers is", sum)
```